# Error When Trying to Upload App Bundle to Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I am trying to upload an app bundle to the Google Play Store, and the play console shows an error message:

> "An error occurred with running the bundle-tool for your uploaded app
>   bundle. Ensure that your app bundle is valid and try again. Learn
>   more. Error:"

I run the bundle-tool on my own computer and everything works just fine. 
Anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery#create_dynamic_feature
you may need this. although the doc is not detailed.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly how I solved the issue. The document only says this will cause runtime error...

Comment: @littledog @WadeWilson I have code in my Dynamic Feature Module, So should I set to `hasCode` to true or false and in which manifest (App Manifest or Feature Module Manifest)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to deploy aab files only, .apk is not allowed anymore. It was made compulsory from august. It was notified already

Answer (score 1):

Did you run "build-apks" with the latest version of bundletool?

If so, there is little we can do to help here without access to the actual bundle. I would recommend reaching out to Play Console support team: they will be able to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who happens to stumble upon this issue, make sure you download and use the latest version of bundle-tool, my issue was duplication of FILE-PATH-PROVIDERS, the old bundle-tool let it slide, latest one does not